# FormView::getName() support in symfony2.3

Tags: symfony

Ive been asked to upgrade an application to 2.3 (part of a multistage upgrade) from 2.1 and Im having a problem where `FormView::getName()` is called

**error**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormView::getName() in ...
```

**code calling the method**

```
public function helper( $form )
{
    $tooltip = $this->help_service->getTooltip( $form->getName() )
}
```

Ive searched [documentation] and indeed its not there so its obviously deprecated.  I cannot find any documentation on an alternative.[1](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormView.html)

Can anyone help please?

**update**

it looks like lots gone from Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, including getVars() which is in use in the application as well.   Ive searched for some support documents but havent come up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure but maybe you mean this: ?

if you use a FormType to create a Form like:

```
 $form = $this->createForm('company',$company);
```

and your formType implements a getName() function

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->add('adresses','collection', array('type' => 'adress','allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false,'allow_delete'=>true) )
            ->add('save', 'submit');
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Foo\CoreBundle\Entity\Company',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'company';
    }
}
```

so this way

```
 $form->getName()
```

will return `company`

Comment: cheers for looking. yes we have that in all formType classes, but for some reason its failing

Comment: i can only assume that for some reason the object isnt being passed to the method properly. (Ive updated my question to show it in a method)